# remote rejected master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to

Tags: c#, git, github, heroku, .net-core

I've been stuck in this problem for almost all day now and haven't found any appropriate solution though there are some out there. No matter what I do the error is always the same for me. So, I created this project to learn ASP.NET Core MVC which already had git init and posted it here: https://github.com/thechaudharysab/IBJOffice

Now today I decided to take this project online and see if it works or not or how I can make it LIVE on the cloud using Heroku (because it's free & I didn't want to use Azure yet).

I installed `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine` and added `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;` in my `program.cs` class and then in it's main method I added:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build();
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

If right now I check `git status` there is nothing to commit as my branch is up to date with 'origin/master' on GitHub. So now I want to push the code to Heroku and for that I'm doing this:

```
git add .
git commit -m "heroku update'
heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/noliar/dotnet-buildpack.git -a ibjoffice
heroku git:remote -a ibjoffice
git push heroku master
```

Every single time I get this error:

[image]

If I write `git remote -v` I get these four:

[image]

Since I'm new to .NET Core so I might have made a mistake or missed something that is why to the best of my knowledge I've added everything let me know if there is any information that is missing I'll add it.

Here is why I think (to my limited basic knowledge) can be the reason:

- The build pack I'm using https://github.com/noliar/dotnet-buildpack is too old and might not be feasible with a .NET project created a couple of weeks ago.
- The code I wrote in `program.cs` might be wrong as I was unable to run the project after I updated the main method it just keeps on loading and loading when I run it locally.
- `git remote -v` shows four may be they just have to be two and its making a confusion and causing the error.
- There are some solution that are talking about a file named `app.json` and I don't have any such file my my project as you can see full project here: https://github.com/thechaudharysab/IBJOffice

So these are my guesses. Would really appropriate any help.

Comment: A 'pre-receive' hook is a script run by git, on the server side, each time it receives some new commits. Ultimately, an error in this script rejects the push, however, the cause of the error is not git directly. Check the error messages : one line in your screen capture says "failed to compile ASP.NET Core app." ; look at messages above for more details, try to look for documentation of what compilation options are used on heroku.

Comment: You have truncated your first screenshot, it is not the whole output and the part you posted does not really say about the reason the compilation has failed. Also, please post it as text not image.

Answer (score 0):

> `heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/noliar/dotnet-buildpack.git -a ibjoffice`

--> https://github.com/noliar/dotnet-buildpack/blob/master/bin/detect

It checks for a presence of `project.json`.

Your project is lacking a `project.json` and thus is not compatible with the buildpack. Hence the `Push rejected`.

This check is extremely basic. So even if you now add this file to your project there may be other issues you are going to run into.

Comment: So is there any latest build pack that I can use? Or how to fix that? As this app that I'm trying to deploy is made using the latest ASP.NET Core MVC versions. I've used noliar's buildpack as it was widely used in the tutorials I was following.

Comment: `noliar`'s buildpack is very outdated. `project.json` is hardly used. Many moved to `*.csproj` which you project does have. Try https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack which is actively being maintained.

Comment: If that doesn't work you can try: https://github.com/androsovandrii/dotnetcore-buildpack and https://github.com/heroku-softtrends/heroku-buildpack-dotnetcore but if it is a general project mistake changing buildpacks won't solve the problem.